# SQL Server 2012 Developer version on Windows 7

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've successfully installed the developer version of SQL Server 2012 on a PC running Windows 7 Professional.  SQL Server works locally.  But I can't "find" it when attempting to set up an ODBC connection on another PC to access this SQL Server installation.  Its probably a basic permissions issue.  Can anyone give some pointers or a reference to step-by-step instructions for this type of configuration? - Tom

Answer (score 2):

Enable TCP protocol in SQL Configuration Manager.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191294(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this in awhile, but often you also have to start the "SQL Server Browser Service" if you want other programs to be able to do things like automatically find and list the server in drop down menus, if that is what you mean by "But I can't find it".  It is not required though, as you can always manually enter the server name in most connection dialogs.  It is sort of a broadcasting service that helps client programs discover the servers in their network.

In addition to all this, the local firewall on the machine can block requests to either the browser service or the sql service itself.  Of course for production I wouldn't recommend turning off the firewall, but when you are first setting it up it is usually best to have it turned off until you get everything working, then turn on the firewall and focus on opening up necessary ports.

As a supplement I refer you to:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-connectivity-issues.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all - I now have a working ODBC connection to the new SQL Server installation.  Enabling the TCP protocol seemed to be the missing step.  I thought I had done this earlier but must have missed it.

And the reference to the blog piece for steps-to-troubleshoot-connectivity-issues is greatly appreciated.  Very thorough.  It has been added to my library. - Tom